# How to make sure all workstations are synced with regards to time

Tags: networking, time, synchronization, windows-networking

For one my projects, we created a Student Attendance System. It is networked, with workstation having its own database, and all are connected to one master computer.

Is there a way to make sure that the workstations are ALWAYS on the same time as the master computer?

We are using LINQ and C# on Visual Studio. A friend suggested using windows.time.com. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you asking for advice on developing software to sync your computers? There's plenty of prebuilt software that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows Time Service. Configuration varies depending on if you are in an Active Directory Domain, Workgroup, etc.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307897